# Are questions about Windows 10 better on some Microsoft forum instead of StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I [asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/960444/granting-folder-move-permissions-between-external-drives-on-windows-10-after-rei) that involves not understanding why a feature in Windows I've used before is all the sudden giving me issues. Either I'm doing it wrong or there's a little troubleshooting needed. Is my problem type not optimal for StackExchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question looks perfectly on-topic for Super User. No problems there!